# CLI - How to select a file or directory with special encoding?

Tags: bash, shell

Instead of copying and pasting it on the command line.

Is there a way to go through the files, or select them via ID's or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting" a file on the CLI? There is no such thing. Do you mean tab completion or getting the path to a file with a weird name?

Comment: What about `ls`, `find`, etc?

Comment: Special encoding in the filename? In which way special? `cat FILE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a numeric `id` to your list of files with:

```
ls | nl
```

For example if you have this files in your directory:

```
file1
�%9Cbersicht.html
file2
```

then `ls | nl` will give:

```
1   file1
2   �%9Cbersicht.html
3   file2
```

from here you can use `grep` and `awk`  to do other tasks like copying. Example:

```
ls | nl | grep '\<2\>' | awk '{ print $2 }'
�%9Cbersicht.html                        # prints the name of the file
```

or print the file contents:

```
cat $(ls | nl | grep '\<2\>' | awk '{ print $2 }')
```